# most efficient way to parse two tables?

Tags: mysql

Given the following tables:

```
tplayers:
  tourneyid  (int)
  playerid   (int)

players:
  playerid   (int)
  * (other fields)
```

given a specific tourneyid (say mytourney), I want to pull all rows from players where there is a row in tplayers that maches the tourney id and pull that playerid row from players.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is very basic SQL knowledge. You should consider taking a tutorial or reading a book about SQL.

Comment: With a select statement.

Comment: yes I know it is.. and was hoping to save some time and have my memory refreshed... funny, in the time it takes for you to lecture me, you could have actually been helpful.

I'm currently working in a half-dozen different languages.. i get syntax mixxed up on things and I used to be able to google this stuff and go to appropriate manpages but now stack overflow always comes up so I thought I might try here for a quick refresher on syntax.

Comment: Here's the way I would do it, but I don't know if this is the best way.. If any non-douchebags want to actually offer helpful advice, it would be appreciated:

    SELECT a.* from players a,tplayers b where b.userid=a.userid and b.tourneyid=1

Comment: I voted to close the question also since it has no future use (too generic and common), but if I weren't so lazy, I would have found a popular "How do I join tables?" question and marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM tplayers t
  JOIN players p
    ON t.playerid = p.playerid
  WHERE t.tourneyid = mytourney
```

Now, efficiency here is going to rely on indexes. Minimum indexes should be on `tplayers.tourneyid` and `players.playerid`.

Comment: Thanks - those are the indexes I have.  much appreciated!  :)

is my syntax the same as yours just minus the JOIN statement?

Comment: @S.ov, Looks the same. You're doing an implicit join, and I'm using an explicit join, which is the preferred method. Also, for improved readability use aliases that serve as mnemonics, such as short abbreviates for the table name, not `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks... it's been several years since I've done MySQL stuff and I just needed a few reminders.